# Laravel "universal to" in development vs production

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I'm working with a Laravel 5.2 application.  In my development and staging environments, I'd like to make use of the "Universal To" mail config option [described in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#mail-and-local-development).  A universal to in development environments ensures all emails go to that address, instead of out to real customers/clients/whatever.

I can't work out how to specify this differently in production though.  In production there should be **no** universal to - emails should go out to real addresses.

The standard approach of using different `env()` values does not seem to work.  For example:

**config/mail.php**:

```
'to' => [
    'address'   => env('UNIVERSAL_TO', false)
],
```

**development .env**:

```
UNIVERSAL_TO=my-testing-address@somewhere.com
```

This works fine - all emails go to the specified `UNIVERSAL_TO`, as expected.  But if I change that to what I will want in production, eg:

**production .env**

```
UNIVERSAL_TO=
```

(or `=''`, or `=false`, or simply omitting this completely), sending any mail fails with (in `storage/laravel.log`):

> local.ERROR: exception 'Swift_RfcComplianceException' with message 'Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.' in path/to/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/MailboxHeader.php:348

`config/mail.php` is just returning an array, so I suppose I could instead set it as a variable and then depending on environment append the 'to' to it, like so:

```
$return = [ ... normal mail config array ... ];

if (!\App::environment('production')) {
    $return['to'] => [
        'address' => 'my-testing-address@somewhere.com'
    ];
}

return $return;
```

But this seems a little ... hacky.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't understand. You try to set it as empty and then it tries to send mail to an empty email address?

Comment: you cant define your email false. 

    'address'   => env('UNIVERSAL_TO', 'my-testing-address@somewhere.com)

and this line should be UNIVERSAL_TO=  in your .env file 

so if you define UNIVERSAL_TO you will use it (production). In staging or  in local you will use testing address. false is not an email

Comment: There should be *no* universal to in production.  See the docs I linked to - the point of a universal to is to catch emails in dev environments so they do not go to real customers.

Comment: dont define it then. use MAIL_DRIVER=log in local and smpt in your production so you will log your emails in staging/local and send real emails on production

Comment: Thanks, but that's not a solution to the question I asked.  I want to use the documented universal to feature, not something else.  I need to be able to view the emails in my client; I also need others to have access to check them.

Comment: Mailtrap is another option, but not as flexible or suitable as a simple universal to.  If this universal to option did not exist I'd make do with one of these other options - but it exists, and is exactly what I need.  How can I use it properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this should work - it leaves `config('mail.to')` as `null` unless `UNIVERSAL_TO` is set.

```
'to' => env('UNIVERSAL_TO', false) ? [
    'address' => env('UNIVERSAL_TO'),
    'name' => env('UNIVERSAL_TO_NAME')
] : null,
```

Comment: it's working fine but should have the second parameter as a name.

[
    'address' => env('UNIVERSAL_TO'),
     'name' => 'any name or set env variable for this too'
]

Comment: It seems the key is to use `null`, in my tests I used false or blank which failed.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this issue when googling for this behaviour. Since the answers aren't perfect, I decided to add my results.

If it ever was broken, it seems this has been fixed now. When omitting the `UNIVERSAL_TO` in your .env file, the Mail will just be sent to the designated recipient.

Perhaps the issue was that you didn't have a `null` value, but `false` as default.

config/mail.php

```php
    'to' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_GLOBAL_RECIPIENT'), // when not found, defaults to null
        'name' => 'Developer'
    ],
```

local .env

```
MAIL_GLOBAL_RECIPIENT=my@email.com
```

production .env doesn't even have that variable

Comment: So your production `config/mail.php` has a `to => [address => null, name => Developer]`, and it works? I would surely expect that to fail with exactly the kind of error I was seeing, invalid address etc?  How can a `null` `to` address work!? :-)

Comment: Thanks, it seems the key is to use `null` or not even have the variable as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I still do pretty much what you call as hacky way and for now I still haven't found any better ways.

```
$default = [
    ....
]

if (env('APP_ENV', 'local') === 'staging'){
    $default['to'] = [
        'address' => 'webmaster@xxx.com',
    ]
}

return $default;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "universal to" is only used when it exists. So the following works:
config/mail.php:

```
'to' => [
    'address' => env('UNIVERSAL_TO'),
    'name' => env('UNIVERSAL_TO_NAME')
],
```

Fill the details in .env (test):

```
UNIVERSAL_TO=
UNIVERSAL_TO_NAME=
```

And don't fill the details in .env (production)